# Pyparsing behaves differently on different machines

Tags: python, linux, arm, x86-64, pyparsing

I want the following program to behave identically on my Ubuntu x86_64 desktop and Raspberry Pi, excluding the call to `platform.machine()`.

test.py:

```
from pyparsing import QuotedString
import platform
print platform.machine()
string = QuotedString("'", escChar='\\')
print string.parseString(r"'abcd\\'")
```

On Ubuntu x86_64 desktop:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ python test.py
x86_64
['abcd\\']
```

On Raspberry Pi:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ python test.py
armv6l
['abcd\\\\']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyparsing is not part of the standard Python distribution, it is a separate library. It seems like Ubuntu LTS 12.04 has pyparsing 1.5.2 and Raspbian has 2.0.2 (check using `pyparsing.__version__`). The pyparsing library probably changed behavior at some point.